# Why is Apex Enterprise Patterns removed from Trailhead trails?

Tags: trailhead

I noticed that `Apex Enterprise Patterns` was removed from the trails section in Trailhead. Previously it was included in the `Advanced Developer` trail. Now it's gone...

[image]

It's still searchable if you select type `Module`.

I am wondering why it was removed?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to the community's attention. I've sent this question to the Trailhead team for investigation. They'll probably circle back with me or post an answer directly.

Comment: seems available now? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/search?keywords=Apex%20Enterprise%20Patterns

Comment: @Raul, yes it's available in search without filter params. Notice though it's marked as module content type. BUT it's not in trails anymore. It used to be in the `Advanced Developer` trail. So people will not see it while passing that trail or any other trail.

Comment: Adrian, thanks for the question, and @sfdcfox thanks for reaching out to us. We're looking into it.

Answer (score 2):

On my side I don't find also a trail concerning design pattern.

Nevertheless there is a trailmix concerning this point here : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/users/bkbroughton/trailmixes/enterprise-patterns-library

The trailmix mentionned both modules : 
- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_dsl
- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_sl

Comment: Well, Apex Enterprise Patterns modules has always been at Trailhead. My question is specifically about a **trail**. Once there was one called `Apex Enterprise Patterns` which was comprised of relevant modules. Now it's gone, and the modules stayed. The main issue with this is that you have to look up each module individually, which is inconvenient, instead of seeing them grouped in a trail.

Comment: Ok exactly I edited my answer. I don't know if one time there is a trail concerning this point. Nevertheless I found a trailmix : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/users/bkbroughton/trailmixes/enterprise-patterns-library

I hope I could help you :)